# format cctime with 3 decimal places

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to format this string by seconds followed by 3 decimal points for example 1.123.
How do I go about doing this?

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt {
totalTime += dt*1000;
currentTime = (int)totalTime;
if (myTime < currentTime)
{
    myTime = currentTime;
    [timeLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", myTime]];
}
```

}

Comment: Please bookmark the [IEEE printf spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html). Anyone that uses `stringWithFormat:` should be familiar with that page.

Comment: I was not. Great link, I've always wondered if a page like that existed but never bothered to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", someFloatOrDouble];
```

Comment: if this is for display purpose, also : use a fixed width font, and a format specifier that will yield a constant string length, otherwise your gamers could get sea-sick if you update this every 16 ms (hopefully you will be running close to 60 frames per second).

Comment: Actually, for display, one should use `NSNumberFormatter`, not `stringWithFormat` to get decimal numbers that look correct for the user's locale.